# Spring Cloud Contract: Prefered way to import repeating parts in Contract DSL

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

When writing a contract for an API i found myself repeating the same things over and over. For example regex validations for complex json object need to be copy pasted.
Thats tedious and not very DRY.

I'm using Kotlin DSL and Maven

I tried to extract the common parts in another file to reuse it. (Kotlin extension functions ftw.)

After trying multiple things to reuse that file I gave up.

The common parts should be as close to the actual contracts as possible. I don't want to export them in another project, and build them seperat, as they are an vital part of the contracts.

I tried it the following ways:

1. just put the file in the same directory and importing the functions, hoping it would be resolved as it would in java -  did not work at all (my expectations were low, was worth a shot)
2. putting it in another maven module, and add that as dependency to the spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin. that worked, as long as the dependant module was built and installed in the local maven repo. if no built version was available maven could not resolve it.
3. experimenting with kotlin script `@file:Import()` and `@file:DependOn` to tackle my issue, no luck.

Is there another way, that I missed? Is there a prefered way doing this?
This must be a common issue, right?

Comment: Please read the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/docs/current/reference/html/advanced.html#customization-customization

Comment: I totally missed that, thank you.

Comment: No problem. I've added an answer. Can we mark it as the correct one?